# Point of having more than one condition variable per lock?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, locking, mutex, condition-variable

I am currently learning about concurrency. I understand the purpose that locks and condition variables serve, but in what cases would one want more than one condition variable per lock?

Answer (score 2):

A condition variable is in fact a queue on which processes can wait (without consuming resources). They do this because they  can only proceed when a specific condition holds (hence the name).
Multiple condition variables may be useful when different kind of processes must wait for different conditions to hold. A good example is the so-called Producer-consumer problem
([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer%5fproblem)), 
when two kinds of processes share a common FIFO buffer - producers deposit items in it, consumers extract them. Producers have to occasionally wait until the buffer has at least 1 empty slot to deposit an item to. Similarly, consumers may have to wait when the buffer is empty. The two kinds of processes signal to each other: When a producer deposits an item, it signals to the consumers that the buffer is not empty; when a consumer extracts an item, it signals to the producers that the buffer is not full.
Although it is not impossible to solve the problem with using only one condition variable, it is much more natural (and efficient) to use two: one for producers, and one for consumers.

Several other "problems" exist that need a similar approach, e.g. readers-writers and sleeping barber.

Comment: You mentioned that the problem is more "efficient" near the end. Why is that? When you broadcast to wakeup the threads, dont all of them check the condition (though i presume only the first one in the queue who meets its conditions gets the lock)

Comment: When there are two queues, you only wake up 1 process (or thread, we can use these terms interchangeably in this context) from the appropriate queue - there is no broadcast in this case. However, when there is only 1 queue, you cannot selectively wake up the "right" process, rather you have to wake up every process.

Comment: It is also important to emphasize that processes do not actively check the condition to become true, they sleep on the queue consuming no processor time. This is why it matters how many of them get kicked off the queue.